# How to Pre Populate a Ninja Form hidden field from an Advanced Custom Field?

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, ninja-forms

I have Ninja Forms and ACF for WordPress installed. I have a hidden field in Ninja Forms and I need to repopulate this with the value from an ACF field.

I tried simple jQuery but it doesn't work:

```
$('input[name=nf-field-19]').val('<?php the_field('rsvp_email'); ?>');
```

As you can tell.. I'm no PHP or jQuery guy.. trying to fiddle around and find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: are you creating the form yourself? or is it a shortcode?

Comment: Created the form in the admin through the NF interface. Then embedding the form in the template: `<?php Ninja_Forms()->display( 3 ); ?>`

Answer (score 10):

Do you need this to work from JS for some reason? I am using the `ninja_forms_render_default_value` filter hook to prepopulate hidden form fields:

```php
/**
 * Populate hidden input with ACF values
 */
function nf_hidden_field_values( $value, $field_type, $field_settings ) {
    global $post;
    $value = '';
    if ( $field_settings['key'] == 'hidden_field_1' ) {
        $value = get_field('acf_field_1', $post->ID);
    }

    if ( $field_settings['key'] == 'hidden_field_2' ) {
        $value = get_field('acf_field_2', $post->ID);
    }

    return $value;
}
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_render_default_value', 'nf_hidden_field_values', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This. This is the way. Although may need to throw a closing semi-colon on line 6 there to avoid a PHP error.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Jquery you just need to trigger a change event :

```
var fieldID = 197;
var newValue = 'compactpro';
jQuery( '#nf-field-' + fieldID ).val( newValue ).trigger( 'change' );
```

Ressource :
https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/changing-field-values/

Comment: Actually it seems to not working anymore since the Ninja Forms 3 Update, you should use the solution of crObot.