# How to add extra data when submitting a WordPress form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, smtp

On my website (selling watches) there is a contact form for contacting a client with us, it contains fields (name, surname, email, phone number and text), when you fill out this form on the product page, the data comes to the mail of our website.
But I'm trying to make it so that, in addition to this, the letter shows us the data of the product that the user is interested in. That is, there are attributes, name, brand, collection and technical description (it is made in the form of its own fields)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71m6L.png)

Comment: The plugin provides a hook that allows you to set default values for (hidden) fields, https://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/field-value/, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49306753/1427878

Comment: thanks a lot, this is what i need <3